# Ubuntu 20.04 does not start at all on HP Spectre x360 (with NVIDIA GTX 1050Ti)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04, hp

The latest version of 20.04 does not start on a HP Spectre x360 (df1745ng, with NVIDIA GTX 1050Ti) at all in normal mode. Safe mode works but I need the nvida drivers cuDNN and performance reasons.

I first tried the update (from 19.19) and then a fresh install. Neither works.

The Installer also only works with safe graphics.

The Nvidia driver is the one suggested from ubuntu-driver (nvidia-driver-440).

I tried to downgrade via `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435` without any change.

Does anyone have suggestions what else I could try?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Nope. I always had this deactivated and is still deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

Use nouveau drivers for your nvidia VGA card,

is black screen in startup, push CTRL+ALT+(F1 or F2 or F3 or ...) to start terminal.

use:
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'

to remove nvidia drivers,

reboot

To restart.

Use till next kernel update the nouveau screen driver, it is what it is, did have this problem many times with this laptop. (nice notebook HP with HP issues)